# Golang socket write stuck in poll

Tags: sockets, go, tcp

Adding goroutine trace. One connection (top one) is stuck in netpoll inside write. This connection is between our own services, so don't expect it to be slow. The issue can be fixed by adding a write timeout but what could be causing it?

```
goroutine profile: total 32685

1 @ 0x42fd33 0x42a7ee 0x429cb0 0x629fba 0x62a086 0x62d084 0x640964 0x5e6306 0x73b75b 0x73b0b2 0x744660 0x5f13ea 0x5fbc12 0x5f8dd0 0x5ffd9f 0x48dcea 0x5f729f 0x460ae1
#   0x429cb0    net.runtime_pollWait+0x60                       /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:160
#   0x629fba    net.(*pollDesc).Wait+0x3a                       /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73
#   0x62a086    net.(*pollDesc).WaitWrite+0x36                      /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:82
#   0x62d084    net.(*netFD).Write+0x414                        /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:336
#   0x640964    net.(*conn).Write+0xe4                          /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:184
#   0x5e6306    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network.(*Messenger).WriteMessage+0x86 /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network/messenger.go:40
#   0x73b75b    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).sendPacket+0x55b    /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:91
#   0x73b0b2    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).Send+0x442      /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:79
#   0x744660    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/manager.(*Sticky).Send+0x5e0   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/manager/sticky.go:91
#   0x5f13ea    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController.(*Controller).Send+0x22a /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController/controller.go:169
#   0x5fbc12    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).sendToService+0x482   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:452
#   0x5f8dd0    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).process+0xfd0     /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:256
#   0x5ffd9f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine.func1+0x3f   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:136
#   0x48dcea    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common.Safe+0x3a               /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common/utils.go:49
#   0x5f729f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine+0x1df    /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:137

1 @ 0x460ae1

1148 @ 0x42fd33 0x42fdf4 0x43f877 0x43f506 0x6299cc 0x62b7d9 0x62ccdc 0x640964 0x5e6306 0x73b75b 0x73cb72 0x74475e 0x5f1ea3 0x491dac 0x491c99 0x5fa486 0x5f7467 0x460ae1
#   0x43f506    net.runtime_Semacquire+0x26                         /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:52
#   0x6299cc    net.(*fdMutex).RWLock+0x16c                         /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_mutex.go:143
#   0x62b7d9    net.(*netFD).writeLock+0x39                         /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:194
#   0x62ccdc    net.(*netFD).Write+0x6c                             /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:319
#   0x640964    net.(*conn).Write+0xe4                              /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:184
#   0x5e6306    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network.(*Messenger).WriteMessage+0x86     /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network/messenger.go:40
#   0x73b75b    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).sendPacket+0x55b        /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:91
#   0x73cb72    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).OnDisconnect+0xb2       /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:179
#   0x74475e    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/manager.(*Sticky).Disconnect+0x5e      /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/manager/sticky.go:97
#   0x5f1ea3    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController.(*Controller).OnDisconnect+0x393 /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController/controller.go:210
#   0x491dac    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/router.(*Router).onDisconnect+0x8c         /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/router/router.go:151
#   0x491c99    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/router.(*Router).UnregisterClient+0x309        /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/router/router.go:146
#   0x5fa486    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).disconnect+0x206          /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:329
#   0x5f7467    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine+0x3a7        /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:150

11385 @ 0x42fd33 0x43e9f7 0x43df52 0x5fc6df 0x49181f 0x5faae9 0x5f94bf 0x5f8cdb 0x5ffd9f 0x48dcea 0x5f729f 0x460ae1
#   0x5fc6df    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).ForceDisconnect+0xdf  /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:502
#   0x49181f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/router.(*Router).RegisterClient+0x7af  /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/router/router.go:114
#   0x5faae9    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).join+0x5e9        /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:379
#   0x5f94bf    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).handleRouterMsg+0x61f /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:265
#   0x5f8cdb    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).process+0xedb     /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:254
#   0x5ffd9f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine.func1+0x3f   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:136
#   0x48dcea    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common.Safe+0x3a               /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common/utils.go:49
#   0x5f729f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine+0x1df    /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:137

1 @ 0x42fd33 0x42fdf4 0x43f877 0x43f4c6 0x4c6d64 0x6f9081 0x704b71 0x460ae1
#   0x43f4c6    sync.runtime_Semacquire+0x26                /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:47
#   0x4c6d64    sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait+0xb4             /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:127
#   0x6f9081    github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.(*Conn).loop+0x8c1    /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:436
#   0x704b71    github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk.Connect.func1+0x21    /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/samuel/go-zookeeper/zk/conn.go:218

11343 @ 0x42fd33 0x43e9f7 0x43df52 0x5f70ab 0x460ae1
#   0x5f70ab    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).readPump+0x70b    /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:111

4332 @ 0x42fd33 0x43e9f7 0x43df52 0x5f6d54 0x460ae1
#   0x5f6d54    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).readPump+0x3b4    /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:104

1438 @ 0x42fd33 0x42fdf4 0x43f877 0x43f506 0x6299cc 0x62b7d9 0x62ccdc 0x640964 0x5e6306 0x73b75b 0x73ca92 0x7447ee 0x5f1fd4 0x491897 0x5faae9 0x5f94bf 0x5f8cdb 0x5ffd9f 0x48dcea 0x5f729f 0x460ae1
#   0x43f506    net.runtime_Semacquire+0x26                         /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:52
#   0x6299cc    net.(*fdMutex).RWLock+0x16c                         /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_mutex.go:143
#   0x62b7d9    net.(*netFD).writeLock+0x39                         /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:194
#   0x62ccdc    net.(*netFD).Write+0x6c                             /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:319
#   0x640964    net.(*conn).Write+0xe4                              /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:184
#   0x5e6306    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network.(*Messenger).WriteMessage+0x86     /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network/messenger.go:40
#   0x73b75b    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).sendPacket+0x55b        /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:91
#   0x73ca92    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).OnReconnect+0xb2        /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:171
#   0x7447ee    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/manager.(*Sticky).Reconnect+0x5e       /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/manager/sticky.go:105
#   0x5f1fd4    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController.(*Controller).OnReconnect+0xd4   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController/controller.go:218
#   0x491897    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/router.(*Router).RegisterClient+0x827      /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/router/router.go:116
#   0x5faae9    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).join+0x5e9            /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:379
#   0x5f94bf    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).handleRouterMsg+0x61f     /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:265
#   0x5f8cdb    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).process+0xedb         /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:254
#   0x5ffd9f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine.func1+0x3f       /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:136
#   0x48dcea    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common.Safe+0x3a                   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common/utils.go:49
#   0x5f729f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine+0x1df        /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:137

18 @ 0x42fd33 0x43e9f7 0x43df52 0x73fbab 0x460ae1
#   0x73fbab    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).startHB.func1+0x23b /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:241

1 @ 0x42fd33 0x42fdf4 0x4061ef 0x405d0b 0x587454 0x460ae1
#   0x587454    github.com/moonfrog/badger/lib/stats/serverside/golang.(*Client).startScheduler+0x94    /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/badger/lib/stats/serverside/golang/client.go:182

1 @ 0x42fd33 0x42a7ee 0x429cb0 0x629fba 0x62a026 0x62dcbc 0x64bbfd 0x54d121 0x54c2b9 0x54c106 0x54c808 0x5807ac 0x460ae1
#   0x429cb0    net.runtime_pollWait+0x60                   /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:160
#   0x629fba    net.(*pollDesc).Wait+0x3a                   /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73
#   0x62a026    net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead+0x36                   /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78
#   0x62dcbc    net.(*netFD).accept+0x27c                   /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:426
#   0x64bbfd    net.(*TCPListener).AcceptTCP+0x4d               /usr/local/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:254
#   0x54d121    net/http.tcpKeepAliveListener.Accept+0x41           /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2427
#   0x54c2b9    net/http.(*Server).Serve+0x129                  /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2117
#   0x54c106    net/http.(*Server).ListenAndServe+0x136             /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2098
#   0x54c808    net/http.ListenAndServe+0x98                    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2195
#   0x5807ac    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/debugger.(*Debugger).Start+0x55c   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/debugger/debugger.go:89

2361 @ 0x42fd33 0x42fdf4 0x43f877 0x43f4c6 0x4c65b8 0x5f2066 0x5f9d26 0x5f8cdb 0x5ffd9f 0x48dcea 0x5f729f 0x460ae1
#   0x43f4c6    sync.runtime_Semacquire+0x26                            /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:47
#   0x4c65b8    sync.(*RWMutex).RLock+0x58                          /usr/local/go/src/sync/rwmutex.go:37
#   0x5f2066    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController.(*Controller).OnConnect+0x46 /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController/controller.go:224
#   0x5f9d26    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).handleRouterMsg+0xe86     /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:284
#   0x5f8cdb    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).process+0xedb         /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:254
#   0x5ffd9f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine.func1+0x3f       /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:136
#   0x48dcea    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common.Safe+0x3a                   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common/utils.go:49
#   0x5f729f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine+0x1df        /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:137

387 @ 0x42fd33 0x42fdf4 0x43f877 0x43f506 0x6299cc 0x62b7d9 0x62ccdc 0x640964 0x5e6306 0x73b75b 0x73b0b2 0x744660 0x5f13ea 0x5fbc12 0x5f8dd0 0x5ffd9f 0x48dcea 0x5f729f 0x460ae1
#   0x43f506    net.runtime_Semacquire+0x26                     /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:52
#   0x6299cc    net.(*fdMutex).RWLock+0x16c                     /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_mutex.go:143
#   0x62b7d9    net.(*netFD).writeLock+0x39                     /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:194
#   0x62ccdc    net.(*netFD).Write+0x6c                         /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:319
#   0x640964    net.(*conn).Write+0xe4                          /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:184
#   0x5e6306    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network.(*Messenger).WriteMessage+0x86 /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network/messenger.go:40
#   0x73b75b    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).sendPacket+0x55b    /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:91
#   0x73b0b2    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).Send+0x442      /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:79
#   0x744660    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/manager.(*Sticky).Send+0x5e0   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/manager/sticky.go:91
#   0x5f13ea    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController.(*Controller).Send+0x22a /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController/controller.go:169
#   0x5fbc12    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).sendToService+0x482   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:452
#   0x5f8dd0    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).process+0xfd0     /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:256
#   0x5ffd9f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine.func1+0x3f   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:136
#   0x48dcea    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common.Safe+0x3a               /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common/utils.go:49
#   0x5f729f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine+0x1df    /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:137

1 @ 0x42fd33 0x42fdf4 0x43f877 0x43f4c6 0x4c67b1 0x5f3391 0x460ae1
#   0x43f4c6    sync.runtime_Semacquire+0x26                            /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:47
#   0x4c67b1    sync.(*RWMutex).Lock+0xa1                           /usr/local/go/src/sync/rwmutex.go:88
#   0x5f3391    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController.(*Controller).monitor+0xc1   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController/controller.go:286

1 @ 0x42fd33 0x42fdf4 0x43f877 0x43f506 0x6299cc 0x62b7d9 0x62ccdc 0x640964 0x5e6306 0x73b75b 0x73fb4c 0x460ae1
#   0x43f506    net.runtime_Semacquire+0x26                     /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:52
#   0x6299cc    net.(*fdMutex).RWLock+0x16c                     /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_mutex.go:143
#   0x62b7d9    net.(*netFD).writeLock+0x39                     /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:194
#   0x62ccdc    net.(*netFD).Write+0x6c                         /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:319
#   0x640964    net.(*conn).Write+0xe4                          /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:184
#   0x5e6306    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network.(*Messenger).WriteMessage+0x86 /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network/messenger.go:40
#   0x73b75b    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).sendPacket+0x55b    /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:91
#   0x73fb4c    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).startHB.func1+0x1dc /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:252

1 @ 0x42fd33 0x43e9f7 0x43df52 0x4558a8 0x460ae1
#   0x42fd33    runtime.gopark+0x163        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:263
#   0x43e9f7    runtime.selectgoImpl+0xa67  /usr/local/go/src/runtime/select.go:392
#   0x43df52    runtime.selectgo+0x12       /usr/local/go/src/runtime/select.go:215
#   0x4558a8    runtime.ensureSigM.func1+0x358  /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal1_unix.go:279

2 @ 0x42fd33 0x42a7ee 0x429cb0 0x629fba 0x62a026 0x62dcbc 0x64bbfd 0x5e6f16 0x460ae1
#   0x429cb0    net.runtime_pollWait+0x60                       /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:160
#   0x629fba    net.(*pollDesc).Wait+0x3a                       /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73
#   0x62a026    net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead+0x36                       /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78
#   0x62dcbc    net.(*netFD).accept+0x27c                       /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:426
#   0x64bbfd    net.(*TCPListener).AcceptTCP+0x4d                   /usr/local/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:254
#   0x5e6f16    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network.(*TCPServer).Start.func1+0x46  /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network/tcpServer.go:22

12 @ 0x42fd33 0x42fdf4 0x43f877 0x43f506 0x6299cc 0x62b7d9 0x62ccdc 0x640964 0x5e6306 0x73b75b 0x73b0b2 0x744660 0x5f13ea 0x73c308 0x73f5cf 0x48dcea 0x73f89c 0x460ae1
#   0x43f506    net.runtime_Semacquire+0x26                     /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:52
#   0x6299cc    net.(*fdMutex).RWLock+0x16c                     /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_mutex.go:143
#   0x62b7d9    net.(*netFD).writeLock+0x39                     /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:194
#   0x62ccdc    net.(*netFD).Write+0x6c                         /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:319
#   0x640964    net.(*conn).Write+0xe4                          /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:184
#   0x5e6306    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network.(*Messenger).WriteMessage+0x86 /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network/messenger.go:40
#   0x73b75b    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).sendPacket+0x55b    /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:91
#   0x73b0b2    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).Send+0x442      /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:79
#   0x744660    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/manager.(*Sticky).Send+0x5e0   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/manager/sticky.go:91
#   0x5f13ea    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController.(*Controller).Send+0x22a /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController/controller.go:169
#   0x73c308    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).process+0x8a8       /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:142
#   0x73f5cf    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).readPump.func1.1+0x3f   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:111
#   0x48dcea    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common.Safe+0x3a               /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common/utils.go:49
#   0x73f89c    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).readPump.func1+0x2bc    /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:112

102 @ 0x42fd33 0x42fdf4 0x43f877 0x43f506 0x6299cc 0x62b7d9 0x62ccdc 0x640964 0x5e6306 0x73b75b 0x73cb72 0x74475e 0x7457a6 0x5f23d9 0x5f9d26 0x5f8cdb 0x5ffd9f 0x48dcea 0x5f729f 0x460ae1
#   0x43f506    net.runtime_Semacquire+0x26                         /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:52
#   0x6299cc    net.(*fdMutex).RWLock+0x16c                         /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_mutex.go:143
#   0x62b7d9    net.(*netFD).writeLock+0x39                         /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:194
#   0x62ccdc    net.(*netFD).Write+0x6c                             /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:319
#   0x640964    net.(*conn).Write+0xe4                              /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:184
#   0x5e6306    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network.(*Messenger).WriteMessage+0x86     /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network/messenger.go:40
#   0x73b75b    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).sendPacket+0x55b        /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:91
#   0x73cb72    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).OnDisconnect+0xb2       /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:179
#   0x74475e    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/manager.(*Sticky).Disconnect+0x5e      /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/manager/sticky.go:97
#   0x7457a6    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/manager.(*Sticky).Connect+0x856        /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/manager/sticky.go:147
#   0x5f23d9    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController.(*Controller).OnConnect+0x3b9    /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController/controller.go:235
#   0x5f9d26    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).handleRouterMsg+0xe86     /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:284
#   0x5f8cdb    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).process+0xedb         /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:254
#   0x5ffd9f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine.func1+0x3f       /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:136
#   0x48dcea    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common.Safe+0x3a                   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common/utils.go:49
#   0x5f729f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine+0x1df        /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:137

13 @ 0x42fd33 0x42fdf4 0x43f877 0x43f506 0x6299cc 0x62b7d9 0x62ccdc 0x640964 0x5e6306 0x73b75b 0x73cb72 0x74475e 0x5f1ea3 0x491dac 0x491c99 0x5fa486 0x5fa25a 0x5f8cdb 0x5ffd9f 0x48dcea 0x5f729f 0x460ae1
#   0x43f506    net.runtime_Semacquire+0x26                         /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:52
#   0x6299cc    net.(*fdMutex).RWLock+0x16c                         /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_mutex.go:143
#   0x62b7d9    net.(*netFD).writeLock+0x39                         /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:194
#   0x62ccdc    net.(*netFD).Write+0x6c                             /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:319
#   0x640964    net.(*conn).Write+0xe4                              /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:184
#   0x5e6306    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network.(*Messenger).WriteMessage+0x86     /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network/messenger.go:40
#   0x73b75b    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).sendPacket+0x55b        /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:91
#   0x73cb72    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).OnDisconnect+0xb2       /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:179
#   0x74475e    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/manager.(*Sticky).Disconnect+0x5e      /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/manager/sticky.go:97
#   0x5f1ea3    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController.(*Controller).OnDisconnect+0x393 /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController/controller.go:210
#   0x491dac    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/router.(*Router).onDisconnect+0x8c         /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/router/router.go:151
#   0x491c99    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/router.(*Router).UnregisterClient+0x309        /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/router/router.go:146
#   0x5fa486    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).disconnect+0x206          /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:329
#   0x5fa25a    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).handleRouterMsg+0x13ba        /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:274
#   0x5f8cdb    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).process+0xedb         /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:254
#   0x5ffd9f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine.func1+0x3f       /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:136
#   0x48dcea    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common.Safe+0x3a                   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common/utils.go:49
#   0x5f729f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine+0x1df        /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:137

7 @ 0x42fd33 0x42a7ee 0x429cb0 0x629fba 0x62a026 0x62be7a 0x640644 0x611d09 0x612b7a 0x612eb9 0x5e60f4 0x73f614 0x460ae1
#   0x429cb0    net.runtime_pollWait+0x60                       /usr/local/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:160
#   0x629fba    net.(*pollDesc).Wait+0x3a                       /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:73
#   0x62a026    net.(*pollDesc).WaitRead+0x36                       /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_poll_runtime.go:78
#   0x62be7a    net.(*netFD).Read+0x23a                         /usr/local/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:250
#   0x640644    net.(*conn).Read+0xe4                           /usr/local/go/src/net/net.go:172
#   0x611d09    bufio.(*Reader).fill+0x1e9                      /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:97
#   0x612b7a    bufio.(*Reader).ReadSlice+0x21a                     /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:328
#   0x612eb9    bufio.(*Reader).ReadBytes+0xa9                      /usr/local/go/src/bufio/bufio.go:406
#   0x5e60f4    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network.(*Messenger).ReadMessage+0x54  /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/network/messenger.go:29
#   0x73f614    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service.(*Service).readPump.func1+0x34 /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/service/service.go:102

1 @ 0x42fd33 0x42fdf4 0x43f877 0x43f4c6 0x4c5704 0x4c6740 0x5f2d6a 0x5f5fcc 0x5f5dc4 0x5890f3 0x460ae1
#   0x43f4c6    sync.runtime_Semacquire+0x26                                /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:47
#   0x4c5704    sync.(*Mutex).Lock+0x1c4                                /usr/local/go/src/sync/mutex.go:83
#   0x4c6740    sync.(*RWMutex).Lock+0x30                               /usr/local/go/src/sync/rwmutex.go:83
#   0x5f2d6a    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController.(*Controller).refreshServices+0x4a   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController/controller.go:257
#   0x5f5fcc    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController.(*Controller).init.func1+0x1ec       /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController/controller.go:333
#   0x5f5dc4    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController.loadConfig.func2+0x84            /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/serviceController/configServices.go:84
#   0x5890f3    github.com/moonfrog/badger/zootils.(*ZooKeeper).watchFunc+0x53              /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/badger/zootils/zootils.go:62

1 @ 0x42fd33 0x43e9f7 0x43df52 0x5fc579 0x491911 0x5faae9 0x5f94bf 0x5f8cdb 0x5ffd9f 0x48dcea 0x5f729f 0x460ae1
#   0x5fc579    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).RejectConnection+0x369    /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:495
#   0x491911    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/router.(*Router).RegisterClient+0x8a1  /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/router/router.go:109
#   0x5faae9    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).join+0x5e9        /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:379
#   0x5f94bf    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).handleRouterMsg+0x61f /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:265
#   0x5f8cdb    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).process+0xedb     /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:254
#   0x5ffd9f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine.func1+0x3f   /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:136
#   0x48dcea    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common.Safe+0x3a               /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/common/utils.go:49
#   0x5f729f    github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client.(*Client).stateMachine+0x1df    /home/rts/gopath/src/github.com/moonfrog/heimdall/client/client.go:137
```

Comment: The reader is reading slower than the sender is sending.

Comment: stuck for hours

Comment: If the client is also a Go app, make sure you're reading the entire response body *and* calling `Body.Close` when you're done with the response. I generally `defer func() {io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body); resp.Body.Close()}()` to make sure.

Comment: it's a tcp connection between internal services

Comment: Do you use zookeeper for some kind of locking/synchronization mechanism? That is slow as hell...

Comment: I use it for service discovery but nothing else

Comment: If it's 'stuck for hours' it is because the reader is reading slower than the sender is sending for hours.

Comment: doesn't make sense. Both are internal services. Those services are working fine even when this is stuck.

Comment: You know that how? How exactly can you tell that a writer isn't outrunning its reader?

Comment: What do you mean by outrunning? It was stuck at that for hours. If it's just slow, it should move forward at some time.